# PHP create a Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Does anyone know how I can create an Array?

```
$string = '3-1-0-1.11,3-1-1-1.12,3-1-2-1.13,3-1-3-1.14,3-2-0-1.02,3-2-1-1.03,3-2-2-1.04,3-2-3-1.05,3-2-4-1.06,3-3-0-3.23,3-3-1-3.24,3-3-2-3.25,3-3-3-3.26';

$array = explode(',', $string);
$last_entry = null;

foreach ($array as $current_entry) {
    $first_char = $current_entry[2]; // first Sign
    if ($first_char != $last_entry) {
        echo '<h2>'. $first_char . '</h2><br>';
    }
    echo $current_entry[4] . '<br>';
    $last_entry = $first_char;
}
```

I need an Array like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 4
        [5] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
    )
 )
```

The first number 3 and other numbers 3 after comma are not important.
Important numbers are second and third numbers in values of $array.
I need categories. Example: if the first (second) number is 1 create Category 1 and subcategory 1 where first (second) number actual is 1.

Comment: Can you provide real output that you want from your string?
At least begin of it?

Comment: And pls change name of question, cause you mislead others

Answer (score 0):

To create an an array, you need to declare it using `array()` feature. Below I have created a blank array.

```
$array = array();
```

An array with values looks like this

```
$array = array("string", "string2", "string3");
```

To add values in an array, you use the `array_push` method.

```
array_push($array, "string4");
```

On multidimensional arrays, declare the array then add the inner array, below is objct oriented

```
$array = array("string"=>array("innerstring", "innerstring2"), "string2" => array("innerstring3", "innerstring4"), "string3" => array("innerstring5", "innerstring6"));
```

and procedural

```
$array=array(array("string", "innerstring", "innerstring2",), array("string2", "innerstring3", "innerstring4"), array("string3", "innerstring5", "innerstring6"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but my Array is more complex.

Comment: I've added some guidelines on how to create a multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

Try next script:

```
$string = '3-1-0-1.11,3-1-1-1.12,3-1-2-1.13,3-1-3-1.14,3-2-0-1.02,3-2-1-1.03,3-2-2-1.04,3-2-3-1.05,3-2-4-1.06,3-3-0-3.23,3-3-1-3.24,3-3-2-3.25,3-3-3-3.26';

foreach(explode(',', $string) as $tpl) {
    $tpl = explode('-', $tpl);
    $tpl[3] = explode('.', $tpl[3]);
    $result[$tpl[1]][$tpl[2]][$tpl[3][0]] = !empty($tpl[3][1]) ? $tpl[3][1] : null;
}
var_dump($result);
```